# Dynamically add and remove inputText field using primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have using primefaces in my project. I need to create and delete field dynamically on my project. Here I am going to attached my code please find it

my xhtml page is

```
        <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

            <h:panelGrid border="0" columns="3" cellpadding="4" columnClasses="control-label">

                <h:panelGrid columns="3"  cellpadding="4"  >


                <h:outputText value="Individual Email"/>
                <div>   
                <h:dataTable value="#{utilBean.attachments}" var="attachmentBean" binding="#{utilBean.data}" id="attachments">
                    <h:column>
                        <h:inputText id="attachment" value="#{attachmentBean.emailAddress}" binding="#{utilBean.attachment}"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <h:commandButton id="delete" value="Delete" immediate="true" actionListener="#{utilBean.deleteAddress}"/>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>

                <h:commandButton id="add" value="Add Email Address" immediate="true" actionListener="#{utilBean.addAddress}" />
                </div>
                <br/>

              </h:panelGrid>

          </h:panelGrid>

        </ui:composition>
```

My Bean Is:

```
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;

            import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
            import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
            import javax.faces.component.UIData;
            import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
            import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
            import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

            @ManagedBean
            @SessionScoped
            public class UtilBean{

                private UIData data=null;
                private UIInput attachment = null;

                private List<AttachmentBean> attachments = new ArrayList<AttachmentBean>();

                public void addAddress(ActionEvent event){

                    attachments.add(new AttachmentBean());
                    this.updateAddresses();
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
                    System.out.println("adress size:" + attachments.size());
                }

                public void deleteAddress(ActionEvent event){
                    int index = data.getRowIndex();     
                    this.updateAddresses();
                    this.getAttachments().remove(index);
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
                }

                public void updateAddresses(){
                    System.out.println("adress sizedfdfdfdf:" + attachments.size());
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    List<AttachmentBean> list = (ArrayList<AttachmentBean>)data.getValue();
                    for(int i =0;i<data.getRowCount();i++){
                        data.setRowIndex(i);
                        list.get(i).setEmailAddress((String)getAttachment().getSubmittedValue());
                    }
                    data.setRowIndex(0);
                }

                public UIData getData() {
                    return data;
                }

                public void setData(UIData data) {
                    this.data = data;
                }


                public UIInput getAttachment() {
                    return attachment;
                }

                public void setAttachment(UIInput attachment) {
                    this.attachment = attachment;
                }

                public List<AttachmentBean> getAttachments() {
                    return attachments;
                }

                public void setAttachments(List<AttachmentBean> attachments) {
                    this.attachments = attachments;
                }






            }
```

And the Attachment Class is

```
            import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
            import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

            import java.io.Serializable;

            @ManagedBean
            @SessionScoped
            public class AttachmentBean implements Serializable {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



                private String emailAddress;

                public String getEmailAddress() {
                    return emailAddress;
                }

                public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
                    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
                }

                public static long getSerialversionuid() {
                    return serialVersionUID;
                }

                public AttachmentBean() {
                    super();

                }


            }
```

I am not able to add textBox by clicking the  add button. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the whole in a `<h:form>`. See also [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked).

Another major mistake is here:

```
<h:dataTable ... binding="#{utilBean.data}">
    ...
        <h:inputText ... binding="#{utilBean.attachment}"/>
```

Remove those `binding` attributes. UI components are request scoped and yet you're binding them to a session scoped bean. This would fail hard if you open the same page in multiple browser windows in the same session. See also [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-binding-attribute-in-jsf-works).

That said, the `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped` on `AttachmentBean` is completely unnecessary. Get rid of those annotations. The `@SessionScoped` on `UtilBean` is also rather strange. The `@ViewScoped` is much better at its place here. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)